# New to lisp, compiler telling me this is a bad lambda

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp and have very little experience with lambda expressions at this point in my college career. This is for a homework exercise with a problem that states:

> 5. Write a LISP function COUNTALLNUMBERS which counts the number of numeric atoms in a list, no matter how deeply nested they are. For example:
>      (COUNTALLNUMBERS ‘(1 A 2 (3 B 4 (5 6))))
>      Returns the value 6

I am using Lispworks to compile my code as well and have been getting the error:

```
 Badly formed lambda: (NUMBERP (CAR LIST) (+ 1 (COUNTALLNUMBERS (CDR LIST))))
```

Here is my code:

```
(defun countallnumbers(list)
  (if (eql list nil)
      nil 
    (let ((elem (car list))
          (restlist (cdr list)))
      (if (listp elem)
          (append (countallnumbers elem) (countallnumbers restlist))
        (append (cons elem nil) (countallnumbers restlist)))
      ((numberp (car list) (+ 1 (countallnumbers (cdr list))))))))

(write (countallnumbers '(1 2 3 a b (4 c))))
```

So far I have tested and got everything to work up to the line that starts by calling numberp. I figured it would be easiest to deal with everything if the input was converted to a list of just atoms, no nesting. Any help making making sense of this would be appreciated

Comment: Please format your code properly. As it is presented now, it is unreadable.

Comment: What could I do to improve the formatting? The most lisp I have seen from my class was very short functions.

Comment: One style guide is in Practical Common Lisp (great book by the way): http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/syntax-and-semantics.html#formatting-lisp-code

Comment: Use [Emacs](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Indentation) for indentation.

Comment: I am reading up on formatting my code better from the provided links, thank you both.

Comment: In order to do it your way, you'd have to [flatten](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Common_Lisp) first and use [`count-if`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_countc.htm): `(count-if #'numberp (flatten list))`. You could write a function that does both at same time, but this would not be simpler than directly counting numbers.

Comment: @coredump: `flatten` creates a fresh list; counting numbers does not have to.

Comment: @sds My point is: "it would be easiest to deal with everything if the input was converted to a list" is true when taking apart flattening and counting, but false when trying to do everything at once. Now, thinking about resource usage is a good habit to learn and you are right to mention it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax error is in:

```
((numberp (car list) (+ 1 (countallnumbers(cdr list)))))
```

since, given your program, this list is read as a form, whose first element should be either a symbol function or a lambda list (i.e. a `(lambda (args) body)`) and the rest the arguments of this function. If, on the other hand, you have written this as a condition to be evaluated (given the predicate `numberp`), then it is written outside the `if` form which has only a condition (differently from `cond`).

Your function has a main problem: it should return a number, but you are returning lists both when the input is an empty list (the result should be `0`, not `nil`), as well as through `append` in other cases.

There are also other minor stylistic issues:

1. The usual way of testing for an empty list is with `(endp list)`, and not `(eql list nil)`
2. The closed parentheses should not be written on a line by themselves.

Here is a possible definition of the function:

```
(defun countallnumbers(list)
  (cond ((endp list) 0)
        ((numberp (car list)) (1+ (countallnumbers (cdr list))))
        ((listp (car list)) (+ (countallnumbers (car list)) (countallnumbers (cdr list))))
        (t (countallnumbers (cdr list)))))
```

Note that `cond` is used instead of `if` since four cases must be checked: when the list is empty, when the car is a number, or it is a list, or it is neither a number nor a list. In all cases an integer is returned, both for the termination case, when the list is null, and for the recursive cases.
`1+` is the function that add 1 to its argument, while note that in the case in which the `car` is a list, the result is obtained by adding the count of the numbers of the car with the count of the numbers of the cdr of the list.

Comment: The usual way to test for an empty proper list is `endp`.

Comment: Thanks, @Svante, I am too much old school and forget this very often. I will change the answer.

Comment: Okay, I see what you did with the condition. I was building that function piece by piece and used if initially but will use condition in place of multiple ifs in the future. I will also use endp in the future. The rest of that is making sense now, thank you. @Svante

Answer (score 2):

1. Do as your teacher says, but be aware that the textbook wants you to write ugly function names. I'll write `count-all-numbers` here (and people seldom write "LISP", but "Lisp").
2. Evaluation of lists treats the first element differently than others. It is expected to be a special operator or a function designator: either a symbol which is [`fboundp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fbound.htm) in current environment or a literal `(lambda ...)` form. `(numberp ...)` is neither, it is a regular list. That explains why you get an error.
3. Use a tool to format your code (emacs/paredit). If you don't have any, you can still use [`pprint`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_pr.htm) with your function quoted to see how expressions are typically formatted (there are still opportunities to layout the code in a more human-friendly way).
   The result is likely to be uppercased. I generally bind [`*print-circle*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) to `:downcase`, like so:

   ```
   (let ((*print-circle* :downcase))
     (pprint '(defun ...)))
   ```
4. The simplest recursive solution is:

   ```lisp
   (defun count-all-numbers (form)
      (typecase form
        (cons (+ (count-all-numbers (car form))
                 (count-all-numbers (cdr form))))
        (number 1)
        (t 0)))
   ```

   There could be more efficient ways to do this, but you'd have to process very large lists before this starts becoming a problem.